# What is the proper way to unload a file in the AcroPDF component in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-7

I'm working with a program designed to list training course information.  The client has requested that we include a copy of the course itinerary with what we're displaying in it.  I had originally been informed that we would be getting a .jpg copy of the itinerary (for storage in a specific directory), and had my program set up to handle that, but I have since been informed that the files will, in fact, be in the .pdf format.

In the original version, I could just set the image component's .picture property to nil to blank out the image.  Using the TAcroPDF component, however, I have not figured out how to do that, or whatever the equivalent is.  I can use the .hide and .show parameters to keep the file from being visible, but I've had points where, for some reason, the component just displays pure white and will not allow anything else to load - it was my hope that, by doing a forced unload of the process after that, I would be able to start the .pdf files reloading again.

I'm unfamiliar with the AcroPDF component.  What exactly is the proper way to do what I want?

Comment: I think the Close method is what you are looking for

Comment: @David Heffernan: This component doesn't appear to have a .close method, nor anything else I would think likely to be one.  What are some other possibilities of what the method might be called?

Comment: No, I cannot find it either. This is a pretty lame control. You could ship your product with a blank PDF file that you load when you wish to unload and unlock the file you most recently displayed. Personally I'd find a decent control to view PDFs.